# My png in R saves to a file but the image is blank

Tags: r

This is my code, it originally would not let me just use dev off so i had to add the last bit for it to work. My file saves in the correct folder but when I click on it, it is just white space. But the r code does output a boxplot that looks correct, it is just not saving the image.

```r
png(file = "Output/boxplot.png")
boxplot(solarfinal$time_diff, gasfinal$time_diff, names = c('Solar', 'Gas'), col = c('blue', 'red'), xlab = 'Completion time (days)', horizontal = TRUE)
while (!is.null(dev.list())) dev.off()
```

I was wondering if the issue could be that I am using the `boxplot()` function and this only works with regular plotting or `ggplot()`.

Comment: Your code is sound assuming that `solarfinal` has those columns exist. Can you create the boxplot "normally" (not into a `png()`)?